# How do I add a mangle rule to my saved iptables firewall rules file?

Tags: iptables, firewall

I've set up OpenVPN on my Debian server and would like to add a rule to iptables. I already have a file that lists default filter rules that iptables reads from (pre-up). I tried adding the rule to the file like so:

```
*filter
# Default firewall rules are here
COMMIT

*mangle
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o wlan0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.230
COMMIT
```

I then try to apply the rules with:

```
sudo iptables-apply /etc/iptables.firewall.rules
```

and it fails.

For reference, I followed this [tutorial](http://readwrite.com/2014/04/10/raspberry-pi-vpn-tutorial-server-secure-web-browsing/) but don't want to use the shell script because it also failed to apply the mangle rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the **SNAT** rule to the `nat` table and not `mangle`.

You could also add the rule directly to the active table using:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o wlan0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.230
```

And if everything is working save it to a file using:

```
iptables-save > file
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know where the mangle/nat confusion happened. I also didn't know non-filter table rules don't show by default when you list them with `iptables -S`. I didn't see the rules until `iptables -t nat -S`.

Comment: @cpt you're welcome, don't worry, happens to me as well. One more thing I learned while testing new iptables rules with `iptables-restore` is that error messages are not always very helpful. Using `iptables` directly will help you to find the mistake faster. Also try `iptables -vnL`